# Adjacent dominos in a train

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Definition of a domino -- a domino contains two squares separated by a line. In both of the squares, there are some numbers of dots (can be 0).

Definition of "double-n" domino set: It contains one of each possible domino using integers from 0 to n. 0-2 and 2-0 dominos are not counted as two separate dominos, so order does NOT matter. A "double-n" domino set has $\binom{n+2}{2}$ dominos.

Definition of train -- dominos are arranged end-to-end. the adjoining halves of neighboring dominos must have the same number of dots.

If g(n) is the smallest number of trains that can be formed from the dominoes in a double-n set, such that each domino is used in exactly one train:

a) Find g (12). 
b) Find g (15).

I've been pondering this question for over an hour, but I still don't know how to solve this problem, much less solve it. Hints/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Label the vertices of $K_{n+1}$ with the integers $0,\ldots,n$, and add a loop at each vertex to get a graph $G_n$. The edges of $G_n$ correspond in an obvious way to the dominoes of a double-$n$ set. A domino train corresponds to a path in $G_n$ with no repeated edge. Note that each vertex of $K_{n+1}$ has degree $n$, so each vertex of $G_n$ has degree $n+2$. Thus, $G_n$ has an Euler circuit if $n$ is even. What happens if $n$ is odd?

**Added:** Here are a couple more pointers. First, note that the dominoes with the same number on both ends — the ones corresponding to the loops in $G_n$ — really don’t matter: once you have the other dominoes in trains, you can always add the $k:k$ type dominoes. Thus, you really don’t need to worry about the loops in $G_n$: you can work directly with $K_{n+1}$ instead.

If $n$ is odd, consider the graph that remains when you remove $\frac{n+1}2$ edges from the graph, no two of which share a vertex.

Comment: If n is odd, then $G_{n}$ would have odd degree

Comment: @MathyPerson: Yes, and if you think about what an Euler path must look like, you can get a handle on $g(n)$ for odd $n$.

Comment: If I drew $G_{n}$ correctly, would it look like a bunch of loops at each vertex 0-n?

Comment: @MathyPerson: No, it would look like the complete graph on $n+1$ vertices, with a loop added at each vertex.

Comment: Oh, I see. Ok. If n  is odd...then each vertex of $G_{n}$ would have an odd degree...so would it just be the connected graph?

Comment: @MathyPerson: I don’t know what you mean by *the connected graph*, but I’m fairly sure that you’re not thinking in the right direction. Do you know any theorem about the existence of Euler circuits and Euler paths?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19639/discussion-between-mathy-person-and-brian-m-scott).